# Передача данных из таблицы в поля формы

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Вобщем есть какая-то форма типа:

```
<form>
<textarea id="1"></textarea>
<textarea id="1"></textarea>
</form>
```

Есть таблица, которая считывает и выводит данные из БД в таблицу, присваивая каждой строке определённые параметры:

```
<html>
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "payment";

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM banks ORDER BY BankName ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query ($connection,$sql);

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table.css" media="screen" />
<script>
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', function(e){alert(e.target.parentNode.id)}, false);
</script>
<table>
<tr><td><b>BankName</b></td><td><b>BIC</b></td></tr>
<?php 
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
?>  
            <tr id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?> 1=<?php echo $row['BankName']; ?> 2=<?php echo $row["BIC"]; ?>>
            <td id=<?php echo $row["BankName"]; ?>><?php echo $row["BankName"]; ?></td>
            <td id=<?php echo $row["BIC"]; ?>><?php echo $row["BIC"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 
}; 
?> 
</table>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(BankName) FROM banks"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20);

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
</html>
```

Теперь вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при двойном клике по строке из таблицы данные передавались в поля textarea?